# Functions not working properly when button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the buttons to unveil certain blocks of text when the corresponding buttons are pressed in accordance to its id.

The buttons, in accordance with the css file, render when a button is pressed via a `fadein` animation. the `"display:none;"` is used so that the text remains hidden until the button is pressed. The css works fine but the Javascript functions are dysfunctional.

```js
function nextA() {
  var x = document.getElementById("partA");
  x.style.display = "block";
}

function nextS() {
  var x = document.getElementById("partS");
  x.style.display = "block";
}

function nextD() {
  var x = document.getElementById("partD");
  x.style.display = "block";
}

function nextB() {
  var x = document.getElementById("partB");
  x.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.text {
  margin-top: 25px;
  font-size: 21px;
  text-align: center;
  animation: fadein 4.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

#partA {
  display: none;
}

#partS {
  display: none;
}

#partD {
  display: none;
}

#partB {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="place" id="part7">
  <p class="text">text</p>
  <button class="button2 text" onclick="nextA()">A</button>
  <button class="button2 text" onclick="nextS()">S</button>
  <button class="button2 text" onclick="nextD()">D</button>
  <button class="button2 text" onclick="nextB()">B</button>
</div>
<div class="place" id="partA">
  <p class="text">TEXT</p>
  <form>
    <input class="text button2 place" type="button" value="" onclick="window.location.href=''" />
  </form>
  <div class="place" id="partS">
    <p class="text">TEXT</p>
    <form>
      <input class="text button2 place" type="button" value="" onclick="window.location.href=''" />
    </form>
    <div class="place" id="partD">
      <p class="text">TEXT</p>
      <form>
        <input class="text button2 place" type="button" value="" onclick="window.location.href=''" />
      </form>
      <div class="place" id="partB">
        <p class="text">TEXT</p>
        <form>
          <input class="text button2 place" type="button" value="" onclick="window.location.href=''" />
        </form>
      </div>
```

I expect that, for example, button A is pressed, the block of text with the id of `partA` appears and no other block of text appears. What actually happens is that `nextA` renders all blocks of text and the functions `nextS, nextD,` and `nextB` don't even load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your elements `S`, `D` and `B` are all **children** of `A`; `S` is the child, `D` is the grandchild, and `B` is the great-grandchild. As such, they cannot be seen unless `A` is **also** visible. Once you toggle the visibility of `A`, you're automatically showing all of the children as well.

To correct this, simply add in four `</div>` to close off your `.place` elements, making them all **siblings** of one another, rather than having three descendants of  `A`.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
function nextA() {
  var x = document.getElementById("partA");
  x.style.display = "block";
}

function nextS() {
  var x = document.getElementById("partS");
  x.style.display = "block";
}

function nextD() {
  var x = document.getElementById("partD");
  x.style.display = "block";
}

function nextB() {
  var x = document.getElementById("partB");
  x.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.text {
  margin-top: 25px;
  font-size: 21px;
  text-align: center;
  animation: fadein 4.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

#partA {
  display: none;
}

#partS {
  display: none;
}

#partD {
  display: none;
}

#partB {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="place" id="part7">
  <p class="text">text</p>
  <button class="button2 text" onclick="nextA()">A</button>
  <button class="button2 text" onclick="nextS()">S</button>
  <button class="button2 text" onclick="nextD()">D</button>
  <button class="button2 text" onclick="nextB()">B</button>
</div>
<div class="place" id="partA">
  <p class="text">TEXT</p>
  <form>
    <input class="text button2 place" type="button" value="" onclick="window.location.href=''" />
  </form>
</div>
<div class="place" id="partS">
  <p class="text">TEXT</p>
  <form>
    <input class="text button2 place" type="button" value="" onclick="window.location.href=''" />
  </form>
</div>
<div class="place" id="partD">
  <p class="text">TEXT</p>
  <form>
    <input class="text button2 place" type="button" value="" onclick="window.location.href=''" />
  </form>
</div>
<div class="place" id="partB">
  <p class="text">TEXT</p>
  <form>
    <input class="text button2 place" type="button" value="" onclick="window.location.href=''" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Note: you'll also want to make use of unobtrusive JavaScript by adding event handlers (in place of `onclick`), though that is supplementary to the problem demonstrated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Adding  tags at the end of the  tags solved the problem